# Setting SNMP interface aliases

Tags: snmp, alias, interface

I've been trying for a long while now to get a set of Allied Telesis switches to display links in OpenNMS. Long story short, I want/ need to set interface aliases for ports. If I use `snmpwalk -v2c -c mycommunitystring myhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18` I get the following list:

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.1 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.2 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.3 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.4 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.5 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.6 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.7 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.8 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.9 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.10 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.11 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.12 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.13 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.14 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.15 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.16 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.17 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.18 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.19 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.20 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.21 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.22 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.23 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.24 = ""
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.25 = STRING: "po1"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.26 = STRING: "po2"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.27 = STRING: "po3"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.28 = STRING: "po4"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.29 = STRING: "po5"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.30 = STRING: "po6"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.31 = STRING: "po7"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.32 = STRING: "po8"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.33 = STRING: "vlanMgmt"
```

So the actual physical ports (1-24) have no alias. I tried `snmpset -v2c -c myRWcommunitystring myhost iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.1 s port1` but it says

```
Error in packet.
Reason: inconsistentValue (The set value is illegal or unsupported in some way)
Failed object: iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.1
```

I am not a network admin and I have very little experience with SNMP. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I found out the MIB that the ifAlias is defined in and I tried this:
`snmpset -v2c -c myRWcommunitystring myhost IF-MIB::ifAlias.23 s 23`

The result was surprising... the switch rebooted without saving the changes, of course. I'm at a loss here.

UPDATE2: Trying to set another SNMP value (IF-MIB::ifLinkUpDownTrapEnable), defined in the same table, works fine!!! Trying to set the ifAlias, using several tools (like snmpset and iReasoning MIB browser) keeps restarting the switch.

Comment: Why do you need to set it via SNMP?  Why not set the port alias in the mgmt cli of the switch and then let SNMP grab it?

Comment: That's an option too, the only issue is that I have only configured the switch using the web interface, and I haven't been able to change the alias through that. Are you familiar with AT switches and what CLI  it uses?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not.  Have you checked their website for their CLI guides?  To me, that would be time better served than trying to make this work.

Comment: I just did and I couldn't find anything. The model is AT-GS950/24 Gigabit Ethernet WebSmart Switch and I don't think it has a CLI, sadly. Running `nmap` only shows port 80 open which is the web interface and the switch doesn't have a serial port.

Comment: In the end, I might as well send an e-mail to AT support, but something tells me no one will answer for a while.